# Can your colleague use your unpublished data for their postdoc fellowship application?

Tags: ethics, postdocs, colleagues

Can your colleague use your unpublished data for their postdoc fellowship application? I think it is unethical. But I don't know which organization in the US handles academic ethics issues if the school does not have an ethics department at all.

Comment: What does it mean to use data in a fellowship application? Are they just applying to say "I'll work on this data"?

Comment: Can you explain the situation better?

Comment: I think the OP means to use the data in grant proposals to support a Postdoc position , or justification for to the department for the Postdoc position.